# remix Cannot find module '@emotion/server/types/create-instance'

Tags: material-ui, emotion, esbuild, remix.run

I would like to use @mui/material with remix run. I follow this example https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/remix-with-typescript/app/entry.server.tsx
Also I follow blues stack https://github.com/remix-run/blues-stack

After `npm run dev` I have next error: `Error: Cannot find module '@emotion/server/types/create-instance'`
Actually I dont have an idea, what's wrong. [Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B55Uo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs import `@emotion/server/create-instance`